# How to setup bootargs to load nfs in beaglebone through eth0

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, beagleboneblack, nfs, u-boot

I'm following [bootlin training](https://bootlin.com/doc/training/yocto/yocto-slides.pdf)  to build my own distro using Yocto.

I have a **beaglebone** connected to my router via ethernet, and I have also this connected to my workstation via Serial

I want to get the rootfs from my workstation via nfs from my workstation,
I have all configured on the workstation, with the file */etc/exports* like this:

`/home/myuser/Documents/Bootlin/Yocto/Source/nfs *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,subtree_check)` (then restarted service)

When I boot the beaglebone I go into U boot enviroment (pressing space) and then set *bootargs* like this:

`setenv bootargs 'console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=192.168.1.39:/home/myuser/Documents/Bootlin/Yocto/Source/nfs ip=192.168.1.100:::::eth0'`  (then use command boot)

My workstation has off course the ip 192.168.1.39, but the rootfs is not loaded into the beaglebone, what am I doing wrong? thank you.

PD: If I follow the guide connecting the board directly to the PC this works instead to the router via ethernet, but I want to do it via ethernet.

Answer (score 1):

"PD: If I follow the guide connecting the board directly to the PC this works instead to the router via ethernet, but I want to do it via ethernet."

So you're saying that if you connect the Beagle Bone and your desktop PC directly, the NFS boot works successfully. However, if you go via your router the network connection does not work?

Your `bootargs` variable does not have a `gateway IP` value. I'd suggest something like the following:
`ip=192.168.1.100::192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0::eth0`

Answer (score 1):

The full config I did was

```
# Clean params for any case use
# setenv ethact 
setenv serverip 10.0.0.89
setenv ipaddr 10.0.0.123
setenv gatewayip 10.0.0.89
setenv netmask 255.255.255.0
setenv ethif eth1
setenv memzone 0x90000000
setenv bootargs-base 'console=ttyS0,115200 '
setenv path-server /home/users/nfs/jduque,nfsvers=3
setenv addip 'setenv bootargs ${bootargs} ip=${ipaddr}:${serverip}:${gatewayip}:${netmask}::${ethif}'
setenv johan-nfs 'setenv bootargs ${bootargs-base} root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=${serverip}:${path-server}; run addip'
setenv johan-boot 'if ping ${serverip};then run johan-nfs;tftp ${memzone} fitImage-Johan;env exists mcinitcmd && fsl_mc lazapply dpl 0x20d00000;setenv bootargs ${johan-nfs}; bootm ${memzone};fi'
run johan-boot
```